# How do I display a custom view modally, within an existing window?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I am trying to build a UI with a main window that displays some content, and sometimes slides-in a modal view from the right edge of the window. Interaction with the main content must be blocked while the modal is open; however, clicking the main content should close the modal. Here's a mockup:

[image: UI with modal not shown]

[image: UI with modal shown]

Please note the user should see only one window. That is, the modal should be nested inside the main window.

I have very little experience with AppKit and Cocoa in general. My approach so far has been to structure my UI like this:

```
Root region (NSView)
    -> MainRegion (NSView)
    -> ModalRegion (NSView; toggle hidden and animate the left edge)
```

and then add subviews to MainRegion and ModalRegion to display content. The problem is that ModalRegion doesn't absorb input events.

What's the AppKit way to build this kind of UI? I mainly just need to know about how the view hierarchy should be shaped and how to block/absorb input events. I think I can figure out the animations myself. Also, the app targets macOS 10.8+, but answers for more recent versions would be helpful, as well.

Comment: Have you tried a sheet?

Comment: I think sheets can't be customized to slide in from the side like I need. Also, I need to close the modal when the user clicks outside the modal, but inside the main content. I think sheets don't support these behaviors. I could be wrong. I just looked over the docs and blog posts.

Comment: note that because your main content subclasses NSView, NSResponder, you can override mouseDown.  If your main content has a reference to the "modal", you can determine if it's showing, and then decide to hide the sheet instead of passing the mouseDown event to `super`

Answer (score 0):

It’s not really macOS like UI but there are two approaches you could use. In both cases you would use a transparent view to cover the main window and to dismiss the modal view in case of a mouse click. If you need a shadow overlapping the main window as shown in your mockup you will need to use a window attached to the main window as a child window. If this is not the case it would be enough to work with a view which is attached to the contentView of the main window.

All the best.